# Firebase Cloud Messaging Support For RSS Feed Notification -Xamarin.Droid

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Cloud Messaging seems to be on the high, but I want to know if it supports Rss Feed Notifications. I have display Rss Feeds on my app using Rss to Json Convertor online and I want to use FCM to push to notifications whenever my feeds update.

If it doesn't support, would I have to send headlines manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't support that. RSS is just static XML, so somewhere, software has to poll the feed for updates. If you want to have true push notifications based on an RSS feed, you'll need to have some kind of server that periodically polls the feed, and tells the push notification service to notify users that a feed they are interested in has updated.

If you don't want to develop a server app to do that yourself, you could pay a service like [Pushcrew](https://pushcrew.com/rss-feed-push-notifications/) to run that part for you. I haven't used them, they just turned up in a Google search. But there's a 30 minute delay, and it doesn't look like you can let users define their own RSS feeds to subscribe to.

Another potential option is [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/subscriber). You'll still have to run your own server somewhere, but they'll take care of the actual RSS polling for you, so that you can just send the push notification whenever one of the feeds updates. You could probably use Firebase Cloud Functions to do that, using an HTTP trigger.

Comment: Looking at PushCrew, it seems it works for only websites and not android mobile applications

Comment: Not true. [See this page.](https://pushcrew.com/fcm-for-push-notifications/) The original page I linked to also mentioned Android support.